# Form generating error when using GET request

Tags: html, flask

My HTML code:

```
<form method="GET" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="query">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

My python code:

```
@app.route('/alumni',methods=['POST','GET'])
def alumni():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.form['query']

        return render_template('alumni.html',query=query)
```

When I'm loading page it is giving error, I know that this error is because when we are loading page for first time we will have no query, if I use `method=POST` to pass queries then my problem will be solved but `POST` will not show the query, I want query to be shown, what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `request.form` is a [dictionary-like object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.form), you can use the [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to provide a default value:

```
query = request.form.get('query', '')
```

This will use the `query` argument when available, or an empty string when it is not.

Update: Since you are using the GET method you should probably be using `args`:

```
query = request.args.get('query', '')
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I use the same thing in my programming answers almost daily, and yet I forgot it, tqs a lot @Selcuk